# Applying Multi Otsu Threshold for my image

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have this image shown below [image: Fig 1]

And, here I am trying to define the threshold to distinguish bimodal class by using the `Otsu` technique based on intensity and then visualise those in the histogram. So far I have written following codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from skimage import data, io, img_as_ubyte
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu

# Read an image
image = io.imread("Fig_1.png")


# Apply multi-Otsu threshold 
thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(image,classes=5)

# Digitize (segment) original image into multiple classes.
#np.digitize assign values 0, 1, 2, 3, ... to pixels in each class.
regions = np.digitize(image, bins=thresholds)
output = img_as_ubyte(regions)  #Convert 64 bit integer values to uint8
          
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(10, 3.5))

# Plotting the original image.
ax[0].imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax[0].set_title('Original')
ax[0].axis('off')

# Plotting the histogram and the two thresholds obtained from
# multi-Otsu.
ax[1].hist(image.ravel(), bins=255)
ax[1].set_title('Histogram')
for thresh in thresholds:
    ax[1].axvline(thresh, color='r')

# Plotting the Multi Otsu result.
ax[2].imshow(regions, cmap='gray')
ax[2].set_title('Multi-Otsu result')
ax[2].axis('off')

plt.subplots_adjust()

plt.show()
```

This gives me the following result. Here As you can see Multi-Otsu result is totally black and does not show the two class of object present in the figure.

I choose `classes=5` but this is bimodal hence putting `classes=3` also giving me the same result.

Any advice on how to correct this? Thanks in advance.

[image: Result]

Comment: Is it all black, or does it look all black the way you show it? I would expect the output to have values in the range 0-4, which are all very close to black.

Comment: No. I want to show in such a way that I can clearly see the two class of object present in the image. Any idea how to do this or am I missing something ?

Comment: Is it possible to increase the value so that I can see the objects

Comment: You need to change how you display your image. Look into the documentation for `imshow`.